# heroku config variables are undefined

Tags: reactjs, heroku, environment-variables, undefined

I have a React app that I am deploying with Heroku. It only has a frontend and no backend.

In my app, I have 3 environment variables for EmailJS: `USER_ID`, `SERVICE_ID`, `TEMPLATE_ID`.

Here are the places I use them:

`index.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
      emailjs.init("%USER_ID%");
    })();
  </script>
```

`email.js`

```
emailjs
        .sendForm(
          process.env.SERVICE_ID,
          process.env.TEMPLATE_ID,
          e.target,
          process.env.USER_ID
)
```

I have read the documentation on heroku [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) which says I need to use the heroku CLI or the config variables setting in the heroku dashboard.

I have a `.env` file that I have for local development with all these variables defined. The variables are also undefined when I try locally with `npm start`.

When I use bash and type `echo $SERVICE_ID` I get the desired outcome.

I have tried both heroku CLI and the config variables setting in the heroku dashboard and the env variables are still undefined.

What might I be doing wrong? Please let me know if I am unclear or if you guys would like more info. Thanks!

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "emailjs-com": "^2.6.4",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Since your application runs in your users' browsers it doesn't have access to the server-side environment. How are you building and packaging your application? Please share the relevant parts of your `package.json`, `heroku.yaml`, `Dockerfile`, or anything else that might be relevant.

Comment: @Chris Hi! Unfortunately I dont have a `heroku.yaml` or `dockerfile` but I have updated my post with my `package.json` file.

Comment: Do you have a `Procfile`?

Comment: Also, I am not manually building my app (or not to my knowledge, this is the first time ive ever deployed an app). My heroku account for this app is connected to the project's github repo. When I push new changes to the github repo, the heroku deployment automatically updates. I am guesses heroku rebuilds it every deployment but I am not sure

Comment: @Chris no I dont have a `procfile`, is that something I should add?

Comment: I can't remember exactly, but I remember running into issues with `dotenv` in React (this was in my local environment though not heroku). I used `react-dotenv` and that solved my issue, but I'm not 100% if it would solve yours. Sorry I can't be more help. Edit: also react-dotenv works a little bit differently, so if you try it out you'll need to change your `process.env` fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I fixed it.

I changed all of my env variables to start with `REACT_APP_` which according to the [react documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/), is the proper way to deal with env variables in react. I also used `react-dotenv` which @Hoobs recommended.